# Summernote executes escaped html

Tags: html, jquery, summernote

I fetch data from a MySQL database, the data stored is this:

```
<p>&lt;script&gt;alert('123');&lt;/script&gt;<br /></p>
```

When I fetch the data normally I get this as result:

```
<script>alert('123');</script>
```

This is fine and works as expected, however when I fetch the data into a textarea which is initialized with Summernote I get an alert like this:
[image]

Somehow Summernote converts the escaped html tags to functioning HTML.

How do I fix this?

I have already tried the answer of this question:

[Escaped HTML in summernote](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33673544/escaped-html-in-summernote)

It did not work.

Comment: [How can I make Summernote not execute script-tags?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47067240/how-can-i-make-summernote-not-execute-script-tags). Please don't say that it's not  related to your question

Comment: It is related but the answer to that question is to just use another WYSIWYG editor.

Comment: I have also seen that thread, it also does not contain a solution.

Comment: https://github.com/ColorlibHQ/AdminLTE/issues/3149.Apart from that I have nothing to help you further

Comment: That is completely unrelated.

Comment: Sorry, not able to help you more. I hope some one can come up with a solution to you. good luck!

Comment: @AlivetoDie It is fine, thanks for trying at least.

Comment: If you can go to https://summernote.org/ and write `<script>alert('hello')</script>` in given editor and then switch to code view/normal view. It's not executing. May be latest version have solved this issue. But I am not fully sure

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to fix it by instead of fetching the data in the `textarea` fetching it in via jQuery like this:

```
<textarea name="description" id="description"></textarea>
<script>
    $('#description').summernote({
        height: 250,
        codeviewFilter: false,
        codeviewIframeFilter: true,
        // toolbar
        toolbar: [
            ['font', ['bold', 'italic', 'underline', 'clear']],
            ['color', ['color']],
            ['para', ['ul', 'ol', 'paragraph']],
            ['view', ['fullscreen', 'codeview', 'help']]
        ],
    }).on("summernote.enter", function(we, e) {
        $(this).summernote('pasteHTML', '<br />&VeryThinSpace;');
        e.preventDefault();
    });
    $("#description").summernote("code", "<?php echo $video->getDetails('', $fileName, 'desc'); ?>");
</script>
```

Now it doesn't convert > and $lt; to <> if it is the `script` tag.

See more information here:

https://github.com/summernote/summernote/pull/3782#issuecomment-774432392

Answer (score 1):

Why are you not sanitising data both at the time of storage, and when displayed in the Editor, or outside of the editor? Typically, in my CMS, I don't allow `<script/>` tags as way to help mitigate users adding potentially dangerous scripts.

That said, there is a PR that is being discussed about how we can best go about fixing this issue. https://github.com/summernote/summernote/pull/3782 information or help would be greatly appreciated to move it along, or even another PR fixing the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Using javascript you can easily fix this. It worked for me in a *React + Django* project. I also used **django_summer_note** and it was also showing data like yours. Then I got that solution:

//simply just create a function like this which will return your data (which one you used with django_summernote).

```
const createBlog = () => {
    return { __html: blog.description };
  };
```

// now in your HTML(JSX) show your data like this.

```
<div className='' dangerouslySetInnerHTML={createBlog()} />
```